# How I can run different production environments on servers?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, teamcity

There is project on react, where is production and development. A project on a virtual server was launched in production. The task is to run another version of the project with a different environment to the virtual server. The problem is that you cannot specify multiple versions of the .env.prodaction file. I tried to run development - TeamCity hangs, tried to change production environment variables directly in teamCity - also does not work.
A set of commands with which I run on a virtual server:

- sudo git pull
- sudo killall node
- sudo pm2 stop server/server.js
- sudo pm2 kill
- sudo npm install
- sudo npm run build
- sudo env REACT_APP_API_URI="http://*.*.*.*"  ./.env.production
- sudo  pm2 start server/server.js

Answer (score 0):

Solution found. I create a file .env.staging and add a new script to my package.json.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging npm run build"
  }
}
```